# How to get string before a character appearing multiple times in power automate

Tags: power-automate

I have this string and I need to get the first character before my date value start. so for example if I have name as ZXDER_20201209220430Z I need ZXDER, if I have ZXDDFR_IUT_23_20201209220430Z I need ZXDDFR_IUT_23. How do I do this once in Power automate. My value after last underscore will always be date value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely more efficient ways of achieving this, but I thought it would help you better understand what is actually happening. The codes are below the screenshots. This doesn't require anything different between the two variables. I was just showing how they both work with the same logic.

[image: Part 1]

[image: Part 2]

[image: Part 3]

GetAfterUnderScoreStringTest1 =

```
@{lastIndexOf(variables('StringTest1'), '_')}
```

GetAfterLastUnderScoreStringTest2 =

```
@{lastIndexOf(variables('StringTest2'), '_')}
```

LengthOfString1 =

```
@{length(variables('StringTest1'))}
```

LengthOfString2

```
@{length(variables('StringTest2'))}
```

String1Delta =

```
@{sub(variables('LengthOfString1'),variables('GetAfterUnderScoreStringTest1'))}
```

String2Delta =

```
@{sub(variables('LengthOfString2'),variables('GetAfterLastUnderScoreStringTest2'))}
```

String1 =

```
@{substring(variables('StringTest1'),variables('GetAfterUnderScoreStringTest1'),variables('String1Delta'))}
```

String2 =

```
@{substring(variables('StringTest2'),variables('GetAfterLastUnderScoreStringTest2'),variables('String2Delta'))}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Brief Answer

Use an expression with the `split()` and `take()` functions to take the first parts of the string after splitting it into an array by the underscores. Then `join()` the results with an underscore.

---

### Details

This expression does it all in one go:

```
join(take(split(triggerBody()['text'], '_'), sub(length(split(triggerBody()['text'], '_')), 1)), '_')
```

[image]

### Breakdown

1. `split(triggerBody()['text'], '_')` splits the text into a JSON array on every underscore that is in the string.
2. In order to know how long that array is, the split must be done again within a `length()` function.
3. That `length()` calculation is used in a `sub()` function to minus 1 from the total items in the array.
4. That `sub()` function provides the total amount of items the expression will `take()` from the array.
5. Finally, the `join()` function puts all the items in the newly made `take()` array to create a brand new string.

I've been parsing text using arrays on and off for a while now, and often I prefer it to using `substring()`, but it doesn't discount substring methods as a valid choice. Often, like with longer text, they are more appropriate.

---

Obviously you can make this more complicated, for example:

1. By adding data after the date, which means you'll need to identify a
   date string.
2. Or, if it were me, I might add failure branches to handle errors in that string.

You could also do it without any expressions, or perhaps only very simple ones, to keep it simple for people that will manage the flow later. You will just need to transcribe the expression into flow connectors.

However I believe that this answers your requirement, which (when you said "to do this once in Power Automate") read to mean in one go.